# Font size not changing in RPresentation

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to change the font in my RPresentation using RStudio. While font-size works for ordered list and unordered list, I cannot make it to work for custom class.

```
<style>
.reveal p {font-size: 35px;}
.reveal ul,
.reveal ol {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.mypara1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.mypara2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.redText {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.highlightGreen { background-color:#40FF00; }
.highlightOrange { background-color:#FE9A2E; }
</style>

ZTest
========================================================
author: Mickey
date: 



First Slide
========================================================

For more details on authoring R presentations click the
**Help** button on the toolbar.

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

<br>

<ol>
  <li>List1</li>
  <li>List2</li>
  <li>List3</li>
</ol>

Second Slide
========================================================

<h5> This is h5 font</h5>
<h6> This is h6 font</h6>

<span class="mypara1">mypara1 font-size: 10px</span><br>
<span class="mypara2">mypara2 font-size: 40px </span><br>
<small>Small Text </small><br>
<span class="highlightGreen">Green Highlight</span> <br>
<span class="redText">Red Text</span>
```

See the screenshot below... mypara1 and mypara2 are both displayed in same size even though I have assigned different font size to them.,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something in the Rpres CSS that overrides your attempt. Mapping the font size to `span.mypara1` rather than `.mypara1` produces the expected result.

```
span.mypara1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
}
span.mypara2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: @ scoa, your solution worked. Thanks! Although I am curious to know why the color worked and not the font size.